# jQuery Showing NaN value

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have the code below that is working fine but why is the `jQuery` returning `$NaN` when I run it via my wordpress theme using the format below:

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

          var $span = $('.amount'),
        originalPrice = +$span.text().substr(1);

    $('.addon-select').change(function () {
        var price = +$(this).find('option:selected').data('price');
        $span.text('$' + (price + originalPrice));
    });


    });
```

**Sample HTML:**

```
<select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-artwork">

                <option value="">Select an option...</option>

                <option data-price="30.00" value="graphic-design-1" >Graphic Design (<span class="amount">&#36;30</span>)</option>
                <option data-price="0.00" value="artwork-provided-2" >Artwork provided</option>

</select>
<span class="amount">$39</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/dYmsV/)

`NAN` is there because you when 1st option is selected `data-price` is not defined.

check if the value of selected item is not null than `if (this.value !== '') {..}` than add the price to the span.

and in the else part i.e when the selected item value is `''` than use `$span.text('$' + originalPrice);`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var $span = $('.amount');
    var originalPrice = +$span.text().substr(1);
    $('.addon-select').change(function () {
        if (this.value !== '') {
            var price = +$(this).find('option:selected').data('price');
            $span.text('$' + (price + originalPrice));
        }else{
             $span.text('$' + originalPrice);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks,  Please see http://www.smithprint.co.nz/product/flyers/ and what its doing

Answer (score 3):

`NaN` is displayed only when the first `<option>` is selected, as it has no `data-price` attribute. Either give it one or add a special case for that option.

Comment: Thanks, Please see smithprint.co.nz/product/flyers and what its doing